# Jmeter multiple users/sessions not working

Tags: cookies, jmeter, token, crm, load-testing

I'm using JMeter to do load tests in SAP CRM Web client and I'm having a problem with sessions. The goal of this test plan is to run multiple operations in parallel. I'm using the same user to create multiple sessions but when i ran the test with 10 threads(users) and i can see in the response that only the first session is running correctly and the other 9 are either not doing anything or assuming/merging with the first session when presenting the results. 
I used Cookie manager to store cookies automatically and I had to JMeter user.properties:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

SAP CRM uses:

```
XSRF-TOKEN;
sap-contextid;
app-contextid;
sessionid;
MYSAPSSO2;
esid;
crm-icsessionsyncid;
crm-icesid;
session_access_token;
```

To Log in I’m using basic auth token (name: Authorization)

I have already looked through all the request and identified all the dynamic parameters and tokens that are or can be directly linked to maintaining the session opened except for one token that I cannot understand how it is generated.

We used HTTP script recorder so the paths are automatically field, furthermore the path is field with a token making it a hardcoded token and it appears multiple times. Being an hardcoded token I can't extract it. It seems to be a mix of multiple tokens that I referred above:

```
/sap(bD1QVCZjPTEwMCZpPTEmZT1SNVpsejRYOEJGOXpzUm5zT2ExSlZRJTNkJTNkQUZCV3RfWkdIdHFOMjN5eXBSaG5aUSUzZCUzZA==)/bc/bsp/XX/XXXXXX_XX_XXXXX/XXXXX.htm
```

This token changes if I record a new script but I cannot understand how can extract this token and print it in the other URL requests.

Is there any solution for this session problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) can be used for extracting a dynamic ID from the URL.

Please see a sample below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Janesh, the issue with that method is that I don’t know in what request that token is being generated. Whenever I record a script, it comes hardcoded into the URL and thus if I try to extract it from there, it will always print the same token. If I try to use the previous HTTP requests to extract it, it does not appear anywhere.